# how to add a user defined string inside a regular expression

Tags: regex, string, validation, floating-point

Hi i am validating a textbox which should accept only float. i use this regular expression

```
^(?:[1-9]\\d*|0)?(?:[.]\\d+)?$
```

to validate it. It works as expected. now i want add a user defined string inside the regular expression so that its meaning should not change. is there a way ??

Comment: You may use an alternation - `"^(?:(?:[1-9]\\d*|0)?(?:[.]\\d+)?|MY STRING)?$"`. If `MY STRING` is a user input variable that should be treated as a literal, then just use `Pattern.quote(user_str)`. (if it is in Java)

Comment: Is it in Java??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate if input is a float number, you do not need a regex in most cases, just use built-in classes to parse the string input, and to check if a string equals another, use the corresponding string method.

If you have no access to code, you may use an [**alternation**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
"^(?:(?:[1-9]\\d*|0)?(?:[.]\\d+)?|MY STRING)?$"
  ^^^                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The [regex demo is here](https://regex101.com/r/yjmVHg/1)

In short:

- `^`  - start of the string
- `(?:` - start of the optional non-capturing group

  - `(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:[.]\d+)?` - your previous pattern
  - `|` - or
  - `MY STRING` - literal `MY STRING` substring
- `)?` - end of the optional (due to `?`) non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string

If `MY STRING` is a user input variable that should be treated as a literal, and *if you have access to code*, then you should think of escaping that string with some regex escaping method (in Java, use `Pattern.quote(user_str)`).